# PHP preg_match is not exactly matching searched string

Tags: php, preg-match, string-matching

How do you exactly find a string in a string?
My code doesn't seem to work:

```
if ( preg_match("/\b" . $needle . "\b/", $string) )
    return 'has-error';
```

Given this values:

```
$string = 'Sub-Category is required.';
$needle = 'Category';
```

It returns as TRUE. It should be FALSE since what I'm looking for is the word "Category". Though the word itself is in the string, it is still not considered as it.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this has to do with the problem, but you usually should [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) variables used inside a regex

Comment: Do you want to find out whether the word `Category` *is in* the `$string` or whether `$string` is equal to `Category`?

Comment: I wanted to find out if the $string is equal to Category.

Comment: If you only want equality, why not use something like `strtolower($needle) == "category"`?

Comment: This is because $string may contain different values and if the $needle is matched in $string, it should return TRUE.

Comment: I modified my question to give a better scenario though.

Comment: `-` is not a PCRE word symbol, so it'd be the word end `\b`

Comment: Yeah, I notice that too.. It is like it's matching as two(2) words. By "Sub" and "Category" and not by "Sub-Category".

Comment: Please don't forget to accept one of the answers. It will help everyone who comes across this page in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the word boundary (`\b`) matches in the place where word characters (`\w`) change into the non-word characters (`\W`). Letters are considered to be word characters, while `-` is a non-word character. Thus, a string `Sub-Category`  has four word boundaries in it: beginning of the string, just before `-` character, just after it, and the end of the string.

To get back to your question, `preg_match` first matched against the `Sub` portion of the `$string` (and fails), then moves on and attempts to match against the `Category` portion of the string (and succeeds). Thus, `preg_match` returns `TRUE`, as in: match found.

In order to avoid that, you have to create a word boundary manually eg:

```
preg_match("(^|[^\w-])" . $needle . "([^\w-]|$)/", $string)
```

In the above example we manually define the word boundary as `NOT (word char OR dash)` while accounting for the possibility of the match taking place in the begining/end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:

```
"/".$needle."/i"
```

So the code will be:

```
if ( preg_match("/" . $needle . "/i", $string) )
    return 'has-error';
```

Comment: Oh well my mistake! I did not understand your question well...your solution is right for your specific case maybe this one is more general:
  "/\b[^[\S]]".$needle."\b/i"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question right. But when I got it right, you want to test whether your string `$string` is **exactly** equal to your `$needle` (*without* case sensitivity)? If that is the case, I would suggest this code:

```
function isAeuqalB($string,$needle) {
    if(preg_match("/^".$needle."$/i",$string)) {
        return true;  
    }
    return false;
}

isAeuqalB("Category","Category"); // returns true
isAeuqalB("Sub-Category","Category"); // returns false
```

Your mistake is that you did miss the `^` and the `$` which specifies that `$string` needs to be euqal to `$needle` from **beginning** until **end**.

Your code did only check whether the word `Category` was part of your `$string`.

---

A good website to check your [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/).

Comment: This for this codezombie. I managed to resolve it by adding [^\-].

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

```
if ( preg_match("/\b[^\-]" . $needle . "/", $validationErrors) )
    return 'has-error';
```

Comment: Hey @user1781041 - as I am still not sure whether I got your question right or not, I just thought I let you know, that your current RegEx ("/\b[^\-]NEEDLE/") will also return `TRUE` for strings like `this is a category`. - http://regex101.com/r/bN3eB0